# Error while using MYSQL C APi, due to passing of garbage value

Tags: mysql, c, file-io, garbage

This is a C program that connects to a MySQL server and executes an SQL query from a text file having a single query, in linux platform.

Here, first a connection with database server is established.

Next a line

```
show tables
```

is read from Text file , named "text.txt"

This is stored in a string called, line. And this string is passed in to function mysql_query of MySQL C API. Then the MySQL database will return the result, that is name of tables using function mysql_use_result.

The above should be the correct working of this code.

But during passing of string,line (containing the data of file "text.txt") to mysql_query() there is some error.

ERROR:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '�����o���+N�J�O�Q�' at line 2

That means some garbage value is also passed with actual data in file through string, line.So how can I correct this.

CODE:

```
#include mysql.h
#include stdio.h
main()
{

  MYSQL *conn;
  MYSQL_RES *res;
  MYSQL_ROW row;
  char *server = "localhost";
  char *user = "root";
  char *password = "1"; /* set me first */
  char *database = "mysql";
  conn = mysql_init(NULL);

  /* Connect to database */
 if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
     user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
   exit(1);
 }

 /*reading query from text file*/
 int fd,i=0;
 char line[300];
 char ch1;
 FILE  *fp;
 fp =fopen("text.txt","r");
 if(fp ==NULL )
 {
    printf("File open error.\n");
    exit(-1);
 }

 ch1 = getc(fp);
 while (ch1 != EOF)
 {

      line[i]=ch1;
      ch1 = getc(fp);
      i++;
 }
 
 printf("%s",line);
 fclose(fp);

/* send SQL query */
if (mysql_query(conn,line )) {

  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
  exit(1);
 }
 res = mysql_use_result(conn);

/* output table name */
printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
   printf("%s \n", row[0]);

/* close connection */
mysql_free_result(res);
mysql_close(conn);
}
```

Comment: The character array `line` is not being terminated.

Comment: Yes it was the error. I made a silly mistake, and was stuck with that.Thanks @roymustang86.